# Creating microsites dynamically based on configuration options using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

The requirement is to create a webportal which can create microsites by configuring some options. Assume the system would be like a  wordpress where people will create some content and configure it with some keyword that need to be prepend to the URL like

```
xyz.mysite.com
abc.mysite.com
```

where mysite is the webportal domain and when they hit xyz.mysite.com, it should display content only related to xyz which configured and created for it. I want to use PHP for it. How this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to create sub-domain in your domain you can create sub-domain by using the PHP script please check the given link which will guide you how to create sub-domain using php.

http://www.webinfopedia.com/create-subdomain-in-php.html